# Nuget reference behaves in a strange fashion

Tags: c#, reference, nuget

I have a C# solution with 2 projects:

1. A class library with a few classes: One of the classes performs authentication using ADAL.NET, so I have a reference to the "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" package (v3.10)
2. I also have a ConsoleApplication that is used as a test platform. From here, I call into the class library to quickly test prototype code and then discard it. By itself, other than using Console.ReadLine() and Console.WriteLine(), this console app just calls into the class library, mentioned in 1)

Now, the weird thing is that if I don't include a nuget reference to "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" in my Console app, it throws an error:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

However, when I simply add that reference, everything works.

I am confused why this is so? The class library already has a reference to the package and the class library is the only one using the package, so why do I have to also add a reference to the console app?

The funny thing is that I then included a WebApp and published everything into an Azure subscription. The same problem happens from a web app. If I add a reference to "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" nuget package in the Web App, everything works, but if I remove it, it throws the above exception. Do note, that the WebApp is not directly using the package, it simply calls the class library (which already has the reference and is making use of it).

Can someone please shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: Completely with you on this Taha, noticing the exact same thing. It is as if the DLL is being stripped out.

Comment: I added a question to their GitHub: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/511

Comment: Using an earlier version of the AD Nuget also works.

Comment: Is your class library a portable?

Comment: No, it's not portable

Comment: I think, the issue  is with the particular package, i.e., "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory". I have faced the same issue number of times for this package, where in other cases, I do not require to include reference of those packages in my console app, its just the assembly which directly consumes its code library requires the reference.. Did you get any solution of this?

Comment: @Nirman: Sadly on. This is still a problem and yes, the package you mentioned continues to be a problem in many other cases also.